# Does the `blocksonly` setting prevent other nodes from sending my node unconfirmed transaction, or does it simply cause my node to ignore them?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, relay, full-node

I've seen this option [discussed](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1377345.0), but I don't have a clear understanding of what is going on.  Since this setting appears to reduce node bandwidth by as much as 88%, I assume it somehow communicates to other nodes that this traffic is unwelcome, but I don't understand the mechanism.  Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This allows the bitcoin node to operate similar to a SPV client.  These nodes advertise their capabilities to other nodes as they peer with them.  A node running in blocksonly mode will indicate that it does not want to receive inv messages from any other peers.  Nodes can supply a bloom filter if they are interested in messages for specific address(es), this is also using the same mechanisms that were designed for SPV nodes.

Comment: Blocks only is not "similar to SPV". It's more like the opposite of SPV.

Comment: @Jannes: it uses a flag that was introduced in BIP37, to tell the peer "Do not send me transactions until I have uploaded a filter and tell you I'm ready", and then never send a filter.

Comment: Aah... in that way similar. I was thinking at a higher levels. Get it. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

I've just read the complete description of the [messages in Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#data-messages), and it seems to me that there is no special announcement the node performs to tell its peers that it doesn't wish to be informed about transactions. I thought that it might announce its disinterest in transactions in the `version` message, but the service announcements don't seem to include such a flag.

Therefore, it seems to me that the node would just not follow up on `inv` messages announcing transactions, but only on `inv` messages announcing blocks. Especially, it doesn't supply any data on receiving a `mempool` message, but it does seem to serve `getblocks` requests.